# How many unique tags are in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

In a [comment in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602199/how-to-break-apart-hstore-keys-and-values-into-separate-columns-in-postgres) I read it's more than 50000, but on the [official website](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags) it says 10486. I assume the latter is the right up to date number, since the comment is 6 years old and the site is the official site.
I was wondering anyway if there's a list containing all the tags that maybe once were used, but they are not in use anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/) is a valuable resource when it comes to OSM tag statistics. According to the [taginfo database statistics](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/reports/database_statistics) there are currently:

- 88 931 distinct keys
- 136 204 332 distinct tags

Comment: I guess this include "wrong" (misspelled or "custom" or translated to some local language) tag/key in the count

Comment: Yes, definitely.